# Prunus cuttings used for pollination: How to prolong their life?

Tags: flowers, cuttings, nutrients, pollination, wilt

[image]

I'm using some wild [*Prunus americana*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus_americana) cuttings to help pollinate my *American x Japanese hybrid plum trees* (hybrid plum trees are [notoriously difficult to pollinate](http://www.fruit.usask.ca/articles/plums.pdf)).

The cuttings have lasted for about 3-4 days in the water, but now the leaves are [browning and the flowers are wilting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KXJ6.jpg).

Meanwhile, my hybrid plum trees are **still flowering**, and **still require pollination**. In the future, I'd like to squeeze as much life as possible out of *Prunus americana* cuttings.

**Is there anything I can do to improve the health of the cuttings (so that they flower for longer)?**

Comment: Maybe planting them in small containers with the ends dipped in rooting hormone? Assuming they root successfully they would then be able to take up nutrients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It occurred to me that my cuttings are not really all that different than the **cut flowers** that can be purchased at florist shops. Florists often use specialized plant food or preservatives to prolong the life of cut flowers.

My local florist uses a product called [Chrysal](https://www.chrysal.com/). I purchased several packets at $0.25 CAD a piece and added the prescribed amount to the water. **It seems to have worked.** The cuttings with Chrysal have lasted longer than the cuttings without the additive (although I haven't specifically quantified what the difference is).

---

**Additional Information:**

Cut flower **[additives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_flowers#Additives)** (Wikipedia):

> According to the Brooklyn Botanical Garden, different additives can be
>   used to prolong the lives of fresh cut flowers. Experiments were
>   performed with various substances mixed with water, including aspirin,
>   vitamin pills, vinegar, pennies, and flower food to test their effect
>   on cut flowers' lifespans.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_flowers#Additives) Each plant was placed in the same
>   environment and the same type of plant was used in each vase.
>
> This research found that the best additive for flowers was the
>   retailer-provided "flower food" that is usually given with a bouquet.
>   Plants are known to thrive in an environment where there are few
>   bacteria, plenty of food for energy, and water uptake is encouraged.
>   Flower foods contain an acidifier that helps to adjust the water's pH.
>   With a lower pH the water and food conducting system within the flower
>   can work at maximum efficiency. The sugar in the food will be used by
>   the plant as an energy source, which had been lost when the flower was
>   cut away from its root. With these nutrients the plant will be able to
>   fully develop. Finally, there are stem unpluggers that will make sure
>   that the flower can easily take up water and nutrients that can later
>   be used to take care of the needs of the rest of the plant.[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_flowers#Longevity) This
>   combination gives the fresh cut flowers everything that they need to
>   survive longer. When tests were carried out in St. Mary's College
>   C.S.S.p, Rathmines, Dublin, however, results showed that glucose was
>   more effective at prolonging the life of cut flowers than the
>   commercial plant food. The experiment was carried out as part of the
>   Junior Certificate Science Examination set by the Irish State
>   Examinations Commission 2008.

Cut flower **[longevity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_flowers#Longevity)** (Wikipedia):

> Once flowers are removed from the plant they continue to grow slowly,
>   but have a diminished capability of receiving the nutrients that are
>   vital for their survival. In most countries, cut flowers are a local
>   crop because of their perishable nature. In India, much of the product
>   has a shelf life of only a day. Among these are marigold flowers for
>   garlands and temples, which are typically harvested before dawn, and
>   discarded after use the same day.
>
> The majority of cut flowers can be expected to last several days with
>   proper care. This generally requires standing them in water in shade.
>   They can be treated in various ways to increase their life. According
>   to James C. Schmidt, a horticulturist at the University of Illinois,
>   originally putting cut flowers in a sterilized vase is important to
>   extending the life of the flowers. Vases can be cleaned using a
>   household dish detergent or a combination of water and bleach. Using
>   these disinfectants ensures that there will be less bacteria growing
>   within the vase that could potentially cause the plant to wilt and die
>   at a faster rate. Schmidt also claims that cutting the flowers
>   diagonally with a sharp knife under running water ensures that they
>   can immediately take up fresh and clean water. Re-cutting the stems
>   periodically will ensure that there is a fresh surface from which the
>   stems can take up water. This will allow the flowers to last even
>   longer. Other ways to care for vase flowers includes keeping flowers
>   away from ceiling fans and air-conditioning vents as this can lead to
>   dehydration, keeping flowers away from fresh fruit of vegetables,
>   using filtered water rather than tap water so as to avoid both
>   chlorine and fluoride, and keeping flowers away from your
>   television.